# Does Java somehow supports .htaccess or are there any alternatives?

Tags: java, php, .htaccess

I have a query in working with `Java` that are easily maintained in `PHP` through `.htaccess` file such as:

My main problem behind it is How can I explicitly allow/disallow caching of *different* files types *differently* in java ? which I can easily do in `PHP` with few line of code in `.htaccess`
I am currently using JDK 7, Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 with NetBeans 7.1 IDE on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` is actually read by your webserver, in this case apache. You should be looking at what your web server supports. Perhaps, you can post what server you are using and someone can make a suggestion

Comment: I am currently not using any server for my app, just Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 web-app container

Comment: Is tomcat not it's own server? Realms could help you here: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1082911